# clicking on button no ID in Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I am trying to click on a button within python selenium that has no ID. The button has the text `Submit an application` within it. However there are multiple phrases of "Submit an application" on the website. The attributes of the website are:

`<a class= "button" href = "(a link)" analytics-on="click" analytics-category="Body" analytics-event="(a link)" analytics-label="Submit an application||(a link)">`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), there are multiple methods you can use to locate an element.
In this situation, I would personally use Xpath if available. Open the chrome developer tool on the HTML tab and find the element you want to locate (or right click on the element and go to *inspect element*). Right click on the HTML tag (in the dev tool) and select *copy* > *xpath*.
Now in your python code you can locate your element like so:

`button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("past_the_xpath_here")`

Alternatively because you are trying to locate a link, you could also locate the element using the link text:
`button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Submit an application")`

Comment: I forgot to mention that there were multiple "Submit an application" texts on the website. So i cannot use that. I have updated the details doe. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What about the XPath selector ?

Comment: I got the Xpath as:  //*[@id="pagebody"]/p[58]/a how would i implement this to the driver.find_element_by_xpath(), when I try to implement it its gives me an error

Comment: This is not the xpath corresponding to the element you're looking for. Are you sure that you selected the right element in the html source code ? Alternatively you can try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"my_link")]')` were `my_link` is the link in the `href` attribute of the element you're trying to find.

Comment: When I go to this website [https://www.ontario.ca/page/oinp-employer-job-offer-international-student-stream] , there is a **Submit an application** button and I am trying to press on that manually. I have the code `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"https://www.ontarioimmigration.gov.on.ca/oinp_index/resources/app/guest/index.html#!/")]') ` however selenium still cant find the element within the website. If you could take a look at it, it would be great and sorry for all the trouble I have caused.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with css_selector.
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[analytics-on="click"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[analytics-category="Body"]').click()

or link_text method  is also a good choice in locating an a tag,
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Submit an application").click()

Comment: the css selector I found was **a.button:nth-child(1)**. The error just said that it could not be found.